# What do I need to be aware of when running a web crawler?

Tags: web-crawlers, crawl-rate

I am getting into more holistic data analysis and would like to use a web crawler to extract data from websites for use in my analytics. To be clear, I don't want to mirror data and republish, at most I'd be aggregating for proprietary use.

I imagine web crawling effects traffic differently than normal users:

- Is it a significant strain on the host?
- Do hosts notice web crawlers accessing their pages, and do they cause problems?
- What is the industry perception of web crawlers, are they malicious, annoyances, or reasonable utilities?
- Are there any rules governing their use, or any industry faux pas to avoid?

Comment: Yes. Bots are often noticed and unappreciated. If you are not careful, you can really ruin someones day. More to the point, you are not entitled to others work. You have to be careful of copyright and you have to be careful to create an opt-out option. Otherwise, what you are proposing is not legal in the U.S. at least and very likely other countries too. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc so if a site doesn't offer an API, I should assume that it's not ok to scrape data, even if it's a part of public record: ie. Census, geographic surveys, etc? If so, how do web crawler app devs sell their software if it's used to violate copyright? Lack of regulation?

Comment: Bingo! You can create your application. Just offer an opt-out such as an agent name to use in robots.txt and a URL in your request to a web page that explains how to opt-out. Just like Google. When you see an opt-out, just strip away all of the data you collected from that site. The problem is this, how do you know what information is public or copyrighted? You don't. And Yes! Scraping and copyright is violated all day every day on the web. Even with all of the copyright violation complaints, little seems to get done at times. However, sometimes, a heavy hand is used. So be careful and kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it a significant strain on the host?**
It depends on what you would consider a significant drain on the host and the extent to which you are crawling data and the frequency with which you do it. Search engine spiders crawl site content very frequently and as long as they are doing it in a safe manner and following industry best practices on limiting the number of simultaneous bots running on a single site then while they are noticed in logs the server is unlikely to suffer from the crawling.

**Do hosts notice web crawlers accessing their pages, and do they cause problems?**
Hosts are able to see every single connection made to their site through their web server logs, in addition many sites use an analytics product such as Google Analytics to monitor traffic and these services often identify if there is unusual traffic such as a search engine spider or web scraper which has swept the site. In certain instances there is no issues and webmasters don't really bat an eyelid but this is generally where the crawling in question is by a legitimate search engine spider crawling for the purpose of updating the search engine index, other crawlers are generally disliked as unnecessary.

**What is the industry perception of web crawlers, are they malicious, annoyances, or reasonable utilities?**
This depends on the nature of the crawler. Search engine spiders are accepted as a necessary evil and a reasonable utility to websites however private crawlers not affiliated with recognized search engines often raise eyebrows due to the potential for a malicious user to be using a crawler to identify any vulnerabilities to exploit.

The basics of what I am saying from this is to be careful about your indexing practices, make sure that the sites you index allow indexing for your use case, and ensure that you don't crawl a site too frequently.